# Using binding attribute causes javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component with identifier

Tags: jsf, primefaces, binding

I have a problem I can't quite get a handle on.

First the context: I am developing a web application using Primefaces 3.5 (yes, unfortunately I am stuck with this old version for now), running on JBoss 7.

There is a form with id "form" encompassing all following xhtml code.

I have a component in my view which is provided by usage of the binding attribute:

```
<p:dashboard id="dashboard" binding="#{myBackingBean.dashboard}" />
```

Then sometimes I would like to perform an ajax update on this component, this is done by using the RemoteCommand component of primefaces:

```
<p:remoteCommand
actionListener="#{myBackingBean.someActionListener()}"
process="@this" id="myRmtCmd" oncomplete="myJsFunction();"
update=":form:dashboard" name="myRemoteCommand" />
```

The RemoteCommand is triggered by a clicking on a Link:

```
<a href="#!" onclick="myRemoteCommand();">Some Text</a>
```

This works pretty well so far. However after deploying this code to production I sometimes get a FacesException:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component with identifier ":form:dashboard"
referenced from "form:myRmtCmd".
```

This is where my problem lies because I cannot reliably reproduce this exception. My question is this: What could lead to this exception being thrown? It seems to work 95 % of the time but being the perfectionist I am (and many of you reading this are as well, I'm sure ;) ) I would like this code to work 100 % of the time. What am I missing?

Before answering please consider these constraints:

- yes, i have to use the binding attribute for providing the dashboard as I need a great deal of control over what gets added to the component
- to avoid using IDs I also tried updating the dashboard by its css class via one of primefaces' advanced selectors: @(.ui-dashboard) - this also does not work!
- yes, it would be possible to use a commandbutton/link instead of wiring up the remotecommand component to a simple html link but in this case the link is rendered by a JSF renderer component and I made some bad experiences with dynamically adding buttons etc (due to [JSF Spec Issue 790](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-790))

Cheers,
p.s.

Comment: For those not familiar with the RemoteCommand Component: Basically this gives you a bridge from javascript to JSF by providing a name by which the component can be called from javascript - set via the name attribute - which then in turn can trigger an actionlistener in your backing bean

Comment: Maybe you can use firebug to check the DOM when it fails?

Comment: Yes it would be possible to use a relative ID instead of an absolute ID although I cannot say if that really solves the problem. Might be worth a shot though.
Currently I always use absolute IDs. 

Like I said up until now I was unable to reproduce this. You know, the usual problem of a developer: "On my machine it works .. " ;)

Comment: Yes but can't you test the production-app from your own browser? If you cant replicate, maybe its browser-specific? :-(

Comment: Sure I can test this from my own browser, and already did ;) I just don't seem to "hit the right buttons" to reproduce this. Maybe I'll take the shotgun approach and run a selenium test in parallel, hoping to hit the right spot somehow. Still this all feels very .. strange.

Comment: If you have an access log from the server you might be able to conclude what the user did up to the error

Answer (score 0):

I also had this weird behavior.

There are probably more than one component bindded to `#{myBackingBean.dashboard}`, so the first one sets the id and there will be no one called "*dashboard*".